# How to apply a xdelta3 patch to a jar file from java code

Tags: java, patch

So I got 2 different jars, one which has been modified.

To distribute my modifications I use xdelta3 to make patches and patch, my question is, how can I patch a jar file from java code?

I am trying to make an installer instead of people having to manually patch.

The command I use to patch a jar is:

```
xdelta3.exe -d -s old_file delta_file decoded_new_file
```